# How to update a class init argument value?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a constant variable be the basis for two different classes. Then I want to use one class to update the variable and then also make that update affect the two classes. How to go about this? Is it possible?

If I just simply update the variable then from what I can tell the objects A and B are already created thus they still have the old var1 value so that doesn't work.

Help appreciated!

```
class A:
    def__init__(self, var1):
         self.var1 = var1

    def function A:
         #Use self.var1 to do something

class B:
    def __init__(self, var1):
          self.var1 = var1

 def function B:
       #Update self.var1

var1 = 123
A = A(var1)
B = B(var1)
```

Comment: You don't explain what you mean by: `If I just simply update the variable ...`, but I'm guessing you just mean you want to do: `var1 = 456` later on in your code and expect to see both `A.var1` *and* `B.var1` change. This will not happen: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Yes, in some way. Do you know of another way I can achieve the same result? I'll take a look at the link as well, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in python are implemented as resettable references, so any assignment resets the reference, which does not affect any other variables. This is why something like: `var1 = 456` would not affect your objects.

One way round that is to introduce some indirection:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, var1):
         self.var1 = var1

    def __str__(self):
         return f'A:{self.var1}'

class B:
    def __init__(self, var1):
          self.var1 = var1

    def __str__(self):
         return f'B:{self.var1}'

var1 = [123]   # a list containing an int
a = A(var1)
b = B(var1)
print(a)
print(b)

var1[0] = 456
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
A:[123]
B:[123]
A:[456]
B:[456]
```